# NEC Rules for Placing Outdoor Receptacles (Residential)

Tags: electrical, receptacle, outdoor, nec

What are the rules for where you can place an outdoor receptacle on your home? I read somewhere (can't remember where) that you are not allowed to tap power from inside a kitchen or laundry/utility room but I can no longer find the source. I am trying to add a couple of extra outdoor receptacles and want to ensure that I will be doing it according to code.

Comment: Knowing where you live would help. Different locales use different versions of the NEC, and some have their own amendments.

Comment: @FreeMan I'm in TX

Comment: The NEC only has a few dedicated circuits! 2ea 20 amp small appliance circuits. 1 20 amp laundry Circuit and a bathroom circuit 20 amp other than these there are NO required dedicated circuits and any other circuit can be tapped,,  there are those that say there can only be so many receptacle on a breaker 15 or 20 but this is only true for commercial and residential NOT residential, I have had to say this quite often because of all the internet electricians that try to say things that are not true!

Answer (score 2):

The counter top small appliance circuits (2)  and the laundry 20 amp circuit along with the bathroom are dedicated other than those most other circuits can be tapped

Article 210. Covers branch circuits.

Comment: Got it. I have a wall receptacle in my kitchen which is on a circuit separate from the rest of the kitchen, it's actually tied in with the rest of the house (the countertop receptacles in the kitchen are all on up to code dedicated circuits). Would I be able to use the circuit which the wall receptacle is on, to put a receptacle outside at that exact location?

Comment: That should be acceptable I usually run 4 to 6 circuits in kitchens depending on the size of the home I find many others also run at least 1 extra.

Comment: I've run into cases down here where the builders had an extra breaker and wires run to a junction box in the kitchen and just capped off for future load. they had it marked as such in the panel.+1

Comment: @Jason actually, no -- kitchen *wall* receptacles are *also* required to be on kitchen small appliance branch circuits.  This is made explicit by the wording of NEC 210.52(B)(1) where it refers to the wall and floor receptacles required by NEC 210.52(A)(1) as well as the countertop outlets required by NEC 210.52(C).

Comment: Three phase 20 amp but not dedicated! Read the rules there are few dedicated circuits required by code. the difference a real electrician and a internet electrician. dining room and other kitchen receptacles that are not part of the small appliance circuits require 20 amp circuits but as I stated there are only 2 dedicated small appliance circuits required by code then 1 laundry 20 amp circuit and a bathroom. NO other Circuits are dedicated by code and this is from a electrician with a general electrical electrical allowing Me to do do Residential, commercial and industrial. Let’s compare #’s